# How to get result from a three-referenced foreign key?

Tags: django

I have models that look like this

```
class Tweets(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default="", max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )


class TweetsLike(models.Model):
    tweetId = models.ForeignKey(
        Tweets, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

A tweet can be liked by one UserModel once only, and I would like to display an un-like button if person liked, how can I do this on ListView?

Current CBV ListView with Form Mixin:

```
class ListWithForm(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = Tweets
    ordering = ["-createdAt"]
    paginate_by = 5
    form_class = TweetForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
        # Explicitly states what get to call:
        # return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        return ListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # When the form is submitted, it will enter here
        self.object = None
        form = TweetForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            newTweet = form.save(commit=False)
            newTweet.owner = request.user
            newTweet.save()
            # Here ou may consider creating a new instance of form_class(),
            # so that the form will come clean.

        # Whether the form validates or not, the view will be rendered by get()
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Just include the form
        context = super(ListWithForm, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["form"] = self.form
        return context
```

I tried editing the templates, and I gave up because

1. It's not the best practice I assume, since it's rendering from frontend.
2. I just don't know how to do it even from Frontend.

I just wanted to add a `likable` as True or False in the context.

---- edit ----

I understand, that by adding `likedBy` with `ManyToManyField` on `Tweets` and I can achieve what I want easily, but is it the preferred style? Is there any other way to achieve what I want? I mainly work with MongoDB, this is the first time I have hands-on on RDBMS, not sure if the logic is messed up on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a change in the database design.

If you have a UserModel :

```
class YourUserModel:
... 
    likes = models.ManyToMany(Tweets, ...)
```

And change your `Tweets` model:

```
class TweetModel: 
    <same_fields_taht_you_now_have> + 
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

With this implementation, you do not need the `TweetsLike` model.

Now, in your template/FE framework, you can show the number of likes for a particular tweet by the `likes` property of the `Tweet` model.

Then create 2 endpoints that would be hit when a user likes/unlikes a tweet.
You can pass the liked `Tweet` instances to the FE for the `request.user`  and see if the current/rendered tweet is in this list. If so, generate an unlike button and the opposite, it is not in the list generate a like button.

Here is an example of jquery that would request the like API

```
$(document).on('click', '#like-button', function(e){
  var articleID = $(this).data('id');
  var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
  $.ajax
  ({
    method: 'POST',
    url: END_POINT_LIKE.replace("0", articleID),
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#' + articleID).html(data.currentLikes);
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, on success it returns an updated list of the liked articles.